# Given $B^T A B= C^T P C $ what are weakest conditions under which $A \sim P$ up to some meaningful relation?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Assume we have, all square matrices,

$$B^T A B= C^T P C $$
and elements in $P$ and $A$ are strictly positive real values. Elements in $B$ and $C$ can be any non-zero reals, thought the two matrices can't be the same. What are the weakest conditions, in addition to the ones given, under which we can draw any conclusions about the relationship between $A$ and $P$ e.g $A \sim P$ where $\sim$ defines equivalence up to e.g. permutation and scaling.

Comment: It is not very clear on what you want conditions? Certainly, you need more conditions on $C$ and $B$ otherwise you can prove that $A=P=0$.

Comment: I said in my question that $A$ and $P$ are strictly positive though; or am I misunderstanding your point? I have edited above to state that I am looking for conditions/restrictions on top of those described above. They would most likely be any type of restrictions on $B$ and $C$ (though I added above that $B$ and $C$ can't be the same).